# Selecting multiple sums HQL

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0, hql, hibernate-4.x

If i run the query below I get a list of Objects that I cant cast to Long

```
String queryString = "select sum(cat.varaible1), sum(cat.varaible2) from Enrollment as cat where cat.created >= :startDate and cat.created <= :endDate";
```

If I remove sum(cat.varaible2) then I get a list containing a long value back.

```
String queryString = "select sum(cat.varaible1) from Cat as cat where cat.created >= :startDate and cat.created <= :endDate";
```

Why is this happening? Please explain

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it is how JPA works with projection queries.

When you have a single expression  in your `SELECT` statement, the result list will by typed properly. You can eihter cast it, or use a `TypedQuery` right from the start.

If you have more than one expression in your `SELECT` statement, the result will be a `Collection` of  `Object` arrays. In your case, each array will have two elements which both will be of type `Long`.

If you want to retrieve a proper result type, you can define a dedicated class to combine your result and use a constructor expression:

```
select new com.example.SumSum(sum(cat.varaible1), sum(cat.varaible2)) from ...
```